# Quel est le temps de la phrase « Elle est morte » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Google Translate traduit à la fois « She is dead » et « She died » par « Elle est morte ».

Est-ce qu'il est possible de dire « Elle est morte maintenant » ? Et si la réponse est « oui », comment je peux les distinguer s'il n'y a pas d'autre indice ?

Answer (score 4):

***She is dead*** est équivalent à « **Elle est morte** » au présent de l'indicatif (cf. « **Elle est vivante** » ). Il s'agit d'un état permanent.

***She died*** se traduit en français littéraire par « **Elle mourut** » suivi en général d'une indication liée à l'événement (lieu, date, etc.). En français non soutenu ou parlé (ou s'il n'y a pas d'indication de la date ou du lieu) on dira aussi « **Elle est morte** » au passé composé (cf. « **Elle a vécu** » ).

Dans la phrase « **Elle est morte maintenant** », maintenant ne peut pas indiquer quand se produit le décès puisqu'il ne se constate qu'après sa survenue. Maintenant insiste plutôt sur le fait qu'il est trop tard  pour envisager ou imaginer le contraire.

Pour signifier que l'imminence puis la survenue récente d'un décès, on dira :

> Elle est en train de mourir (*She is dying*)
>
> Elle vient de mourir (*She just died*)

Answer (score 4):

I've answered in English, since it's my native language, but I'll attempt a translation to French! :|

"She is dead" is the simple present tense. "morte" in this case, is an adjective

```
Subject - verb - adjective
She       is     dead
Elle      est    morte
```

"She died" is simple past tense. However, Google has used Past Perfect tense to translate<sup>1</sup>. In this case, "morte" is the past participle.

```
Subject - simple past
She       died
Elle      mourut

Google has used:
Subject - auxiliary verb - past participle
Elle      est              morte
She       has              died            (English uses "to have" as the auxiliary)
```

> comment je peux les distinguer ..

Sometimes language is ambiguous, ask another question to clarify :)

---

*Please feel free to correct any mistakes!*

"She is dead" est le présent de l'indicatif. En ce cas, "morte" est un adjectif.

```
Sujet - verbe - adjectif
She     is      dead
Elle    est     morte
```

"She died" est le passé simple, mais Google a utilisé le passé composé dans sa traduction. Dans cet exemple, "morte" est le participe passé.

```
sujet -  passé simple
She      died
Elle     mourut

Google a utilisé:
Sujet - verbe auxiliaire - participe passé
Elle    est                morte
She     has                died             (L'anglais utilise l'auxiliaire "avoir")
```

> comment je peux les distinguer ..

Quelquefois des langues sont ambigües, tu peux poser une autre question. ;)

<sup>1. [This site](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/passecompose.htm) claims is is the most common, so it seems reasonable as a default</sup>

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the corrections. Far fewer than I normally get ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Elle est morte* est un passé composé.  *Mourir* comme une série d'autres verbes (*aller*, *venir*, *entrer*, *sortir*, *naître*, ... et les verbes pronominaux) se conjugue aux temps composés avec *être* et non *avoir*. (Et donc n'ont pas de voix passive, celle-ci étant formée par l'utilisation de *être* plutôt qu'*avoir* comme auxiliaire; ce n'est pas un problème ces verbes sont intransitifs).

*She died* se traduirait plutôt par *elle mourut*, mais le passé simple est quasiment inutilisé en dehors des narrations, le passé composé le remplaçant dans les autres contextes.

Comment: « Elle est morte » n'est pas nécessairement un passé composé. Cela peut être un présent quand, par exemple, la phrase est opposée à « elle est vivante ».